# MVC Application Change Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have a very peculiar problem at the moment.

We have a MVC system with 10 users working simultaniously. Everything is working fine to a point, and then for no apparent reason, the system change one user's session id (the Chrome Browser session id) to another users' session id.

As a result the system then starts behaving very badly (which I think is obvious).

What could possibly cause this to happen ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Yeah, no, that doesn't happen. Are you using static variables? Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] that shows all relevant code and actions you used to determine this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried to reproduce this on a separate example but I am unable to replicate the problem. Is there maybe any good reasources on MVC Session handling that I can read to try and gain more info ?